# How to loop an object in Typescript? Element implicitly has an 'any' type because index expression is not of type 'number'

Tags: javascript, typescript

Getting

> Element implicitly has an **'any'** type because index expression is not of type **'number'**.

```js
interface User {
    name: string;
    username: string;
    profileImage: string;
}

let user:User = {
    name: 'john',
    profileImage: './1.jpg',
    username: 'john',
}

for(let userData of Object.keys(user)){
    console.log(userData[userData])
}
```

Comment: Your question is not particularly clear from just a title. Perhaps describe the problem you're having more fully.

Comment: [Please search the error before asking](https://www.google.com/search?q=element+implicitly+has+an+%27any%27+type+because+index+expression+is+not+of+type+%27number%27+site:stackoverflow.com)

Comment: Try `Object.keys(user) as (keyof User)[]`

Comment: @OrkhanAlikhanov not a very good idea. `user` might have extra keys that aren't in `User`. That might break the code.

Answer (score 0):

You can try

```
interface User {
    name: string;
    username: string;
    profileImage: string;
}

let user:User = {
    name: 'john',
    profileImage: './1.jpg',
    username: 'john',
}

for(let key in user){
    console.log(user[key as keyof User])
}
```

Comment: `u = {name: "Fred", username: "fred", profileImage: ./1.jpg", hello: "world"}; user = u;` now the loop will go through `hello` but that's not a key of `User`.

Comment: that is expected, since user is typed User, that is what typescript can safely infer.

Comment: Yet, that's also the reason `key` is not automatically typed as `keyof User` in this code. TS will avoid making that inference as it can very easily be wrong.